# Убиваем клавиатуру при выходе из приложения

Tags: java, android, клавиатура

В методе `onStart` вывожу свою клавиатуру:

```
if (allTags.isEmpty()) {
        Utils.showSystemKeyboard(true, tagNameInputView);
    }
```

Но при выходе из приложения кнопкой home, клавиатура остаётся на дисплее. Как правильно уничтожать все ненужные элементы, в данном случае клавиаутуру.
Пробую так, но на китайском телефоне клавиатуру не убирает, в отличии от nexus'a.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Utils.hideSystemKeyboard(tagNameInputView);
}
```

Метод скрытия клавиатуры:

```
public static void hideSystemKeyboard(EditText view) {
    if (view != null) {
        ((InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте сначала
Utils.showSystemKeyboard(false, tagNameInputView);

а потом только  super.onStop(); ->  строчки местами поменяйте

Comment: @AndrewGrow пробовал и так, к сожалению не подходит данный вариант.

Comment: Скорее всего дело в реализации метода показа скрытия. В целом-то всё верно

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вроде как и с методом проблем быть не должно. Добавил метод.

Comment: Может в манифест ещё что-то поменять? Или программно попробовать сменить softInputMode

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я использую фрагменты. А решение типо `getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);` не совсем подходит, во всяком случае как пробую я.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При реализации метода `showSystemKeyboard` использовал константу: `SHOW_FORCED` , как оказалось в ней и крылась проблема, которую нашёл [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32697487/6387618).

Также если сомневатесь какую константу следует использовать, можете подчеркнуть здесь много полезного: [официальная документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html).

Также думаю будет полезным [следующий ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17789187/6387618).