# Открываем клавиатуру сразу

Tags: java, android, клавиатура

Существует два метода: `showSystemKeyboard` и `hideSystemKeyboard`. Думаю всё пока логично, один метод показывает клавиатуру, другой её скрывает.

Метод показа клавиатуры `showSystemKeyboard` вызываю в методе onStart():

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (allAvailableTags.isEmpty() && selectedTags.isEmpty()) {
        Utils.showSystemKeyboard(tagNameInputView);
    }
}
```

Сам метод `showSystemKeyboard`:

```
public static void showSystemKeyboard(EditText view) {
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы при вызове диалога в моем классе TagDialog, где реализован метод onStart() клавиатура открывалась сразу. Оговорюсь сразу константа SHOW_FORCED сразу не подходит. Кому интересно почему, следуем [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603653/%D0%A3%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/604017#604017).

Пробовал следующим образом:

```
    tagNameInputView.requestFocus();
    tagNameInputView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (allAvailableTags.isEmpty() && selectedTags.isEmpty()) {
                InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                keyboard.showSoftInput(tagNameInputView, 0);
            }
        }
    },200);

    tagNameInputView.requestFocus();
    tagNameInputView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(tagNameInputView.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    },200);
```

Но всё равно приходится нажимать на поле, прежде чем откроется моя клавиатура.

Comment: Попробуйте через postDelayed requestFocus на поле ввода сделать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб к сожалению не вышло. По-прежнему приходится нажимать на EditText прежде чем откроется клавиатура.

Comment: Я имел в виду в т.ч. и запрос фокуса отложенно сделать, тоже внутри run

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не совсем понимаю как именно. Возможно наглядно показать?

Comment: Просто перенесите tagNameInputView.requestFocus(); на 4 строки вниз\

Comment: @ЮрийСПб увы не сработало.

Comment: Попробуйте так ещё: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17238023/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сейчас опробуем, кстати не подскажете что за значения 200 идут после run?

Comment: Это задержка перед вызовом run в милисекундах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, пригодился [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17238023/6387618) ЮрияСПБ.

У себя реализовал в методе onCreateView следующим образом:

```
 if (allTags.isEmpty()) {
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mActivityContext.get().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    if (hasFocus) {
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, InputMethodManager.RESULT_SHOWN);
                    } else {
                        if (imm.isActive(v))
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.RESULT_HIDDEN);
                    }
                }
            });
```

После этого нужно вызвать requestFocus() в нужном месте на EditText  и клавиатура откроется.